# p:lineChart not rendering

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to create a new chart in PrimeFaces 3.5RC1 but for some reason when all the data have been collected and populated in the chart it does not display on the screen. I know there is nothing wrong with the Java code because it is working but the chart is blank.

Please see java and xhtml code below:

Java Bean:

```
public void searchMonthTotals() {

    String sql = null;

    if(retailID.equals("999") && billerID.equals("999")){
    sql = "WITH CTE AS("
            + " SELECT Value,DAY(IntervalStartTime) AS DAY,MONTH(IntervalStartTime) AS MONTH,YEAR(IntervalStartTime) AS YEAR, "
            + " CASE WHEN MONTH(IntervalStartTime) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 'Current' ELSE 'Previous' END AS Type "
            + " FROM tblpay@Stat s (nolock) "
            + " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPay@StatConfig c (nolock) ON s.configId = c.id "
            + " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblpay@StatSlot l (nolock) ON s.slotId = l.id "
            + " WHERE IntervalStartTime >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) "
            + " AND IntervalEndTime <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))  "
            + " AND s.configId = " + configID
            + " GROUP BY IntervalStartTime,value) "
            + " SELECT SUM(Value) AS Value, DAY,MONTH,YEAR,Type "
            + " FROM CTE "
            + " GROUP BY DAY,Type,MONTH,YEAR "
            + " ORDER BY Type ";
    }else if(billerID.equals("999")){
        sql = "WITH CTE AS("
            + " SELECT cm.Name AS Network,Value,DAY(IntervalStartTime) AS DAY,MONTH(IntervalStartTime) AS MONTH,YEAR(IntervalStartTime) AS YEAR, "
            + " CASE WHEN MONTH(IntervalStartTime) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 'Current' ELSE 'Previous' END AS Type "
            + " FROM tblpay@Stat s (nolock) "
            + " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPay@StatConfig c (nolock) ON s.configId = c.id "
            + " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblpay@StatSlot l (nolock) ON s.slotId = l.id "
            + " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblpay@company cm (nolock) ON s.networkId = cm.RecID "    
            + " WHERE IntervalStartTime >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) "
            + " AND IntervalEndTime <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))  "
            + " AND s.configId = " + configID
            + " AND s.networkId = " + retailID  
            + " GROUP BY cm.Name,IntervalStartTime,value) "
            + " SELECT Network,SUM(Value) AS Value, DAY,MONTH,YEAR,Type "
            + " FROM CTE "
            + " GROUP BY Network,DAY,Type,MONTH,YEAR "
            + " ORDER BY Network,Type ";
    }else if(retailID.equals("999")){
      sql = "WITH CTE AS("
            + " SELECT cm.Name AS Biller,Value,DAY(IntervalStartTime) AS DAY,MONTH(IntervalStartTime) AS MONTH,YEAR(IntervalStartTime) AS YEAR, "
            + " CASE WHEN MONTH(IntervalStartTime) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 'Current' ELSE 'Previous' END AS Type "
            + " FROM tblpay@Stat s (nolock) "
            + " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPay@StatConfig c (nolock) ON s.configId = c.id "
            + " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblpay@StatSlot l (nolock) ON s.slotId = l.id "
            + " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblpay@company cm (nolock) ON s.issuerId = cm.RecID "    
            + " WHERE IntervalStartTime >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) "
            + " AND IntervalEndTime <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))  "
            + " AND s.configId = " + configID
            + " AND s.networkId = " + retailID  
            + " GROUP BY cm.Name,IntervalStartTime,value) "
            + " SELECT Biller,SUM(Value) AS Value, DAY,MONTH,YEAR,Type "
            + " FROM CTE "
            + " GROUP BY Biller,DAY,Type,MONTH,YEAR "
            + " ORDER BY Biller,Type ";  
    }else{
    sql =  " WITH CTE AS( "
    +    " SELECT cm.Name AS Network,co.Name AS Biller,DAY(IntervalStartTime) AS DAY,MONTH(IntervalStartTime) AS MONTH,YEAR(IntervalStartTime) AS YEAR,  "
    +    " CASE WHEN MONTH(IntervalStartTime) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 'Current' ELSE 'Previous' END AS Type "
    +    " FROM tblpay@Stat s (nolock) "
    +    " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPay@StatConfig c (nolock) ON s.configId = c.id "
    +    " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblpay@StatSlot l (nolock) ON s.slotId = l.id "
    +    " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblpay@company cm (nolock) ON s.networkId = cm.RecID "
    +    " LEFT OUTER JOIN tblpay@company co (nolock) ON s.issuerId = co.RecID "
    +    " WHERE IntervalStartTime >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) "
    +    " AND IntervalEndTime <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)) "
    +    " AND s.configId = " + configID
    +    " AND s.networkId = " + retailID
    +    " AND s.issuerId = " + billerID
    +    " GROUP BY IntervalStartTime,cm.Name,value,co.Name) "
    +    " SELECT Network,Biller, SUM(Value) AS Value,DAY,MONTH,YEAR,Type "
    +    " FROM CTE "
    +    " GROUP BY Network,DAY,MONTH,YEAR,Type,Biller "
    +    " ORDER BY Network,Type ";
    }

    try {
        Connection con = db.getDBConnection(DatabaseTypes.TRANSACTION_DATABASE);
        ResultSet rs = DatabaseHandler.executeQuery(con, sql);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        maxTransactions = 0;
        maxDays = 31;
        boolean isEmpty = !rs.first();
        if (!isEmpty) {
            monthTotalsPrevious = new ArrayList<MonthlyGraphs>();
            monthTotalsCurrent = new ArrayList<MonthlyGraphs>();
        }
        rs.beforeFirst();
        while (rs.next()) {
            MonthlyGraphs t = new MonthlyGraphs();
            Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal2.set(rs.getInt("YEAR"), rs.getInt("MONTH") - 1, rs.getInt("DAY"));
            t.setDate(dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime()));
            t.setTotalTransactions(rs.getInt("Value"));
            t.setDay(rs.getInt("DAY"));
            if (rs.getString("Type").equals("Current")) {
                monthTotalsCurrent.add(t);
            } else {
                monthTotalsPrevious.add(t);
            }
            if (t.getTotalTransactions() > maxTransactions) {
                maxTransactions = t.getTotalTransactions();
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        con.close();
        createCategoryModel();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "An error occurred.", e.getMessage()));
    }
}

private void createCategoryModel() {

    chartModel = new CartesianChartModel();

    ChartSeries dailyTotalsPrevious = new ChartSeries();
    dailyTotalsPrevious.setLabel("Previous");
    for (int i = 0; i < monthTotalsPrevious.size(); i++) {
        dailyTotalsPrevious.set(monthTotalsPrevious.get(i).getDay(), monthTotalsPrevious.get(i).getTotalTransactions());
    }
    chartModel.addSeries(dailyTotalsPrevious);

    ChartSeries dailyTotalsCurrent = new ChartSeries();
    dailyTotalsCurrent.setLabel("Current");
    for (int i = 0; i < monthTotalsCurrent.size(); i++) {
        dailyTotalsCurrent.set(monthTotalsCurrent.get(i).getDay(), monthTotalsCurrent.get(i).getTotalTransactions());
    }
    chartModel.addSeries(dailyTotalsCurrent);


}
```

xhtml page:

```
                    <p:toolbar id ="graphtool">  
                        <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="6" cellpadding="5" >                     

                     <p:selectOneMenu id="billIssuerSelect" value="#{graphsBean.billerID}" style="width:250px" > 
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{generalBean.billIssuerList}" var="b" itemValue="#{b.billIssuerId}" itemLabel="#{b.billIssuerName}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>       

                        <p:selectOneMenu id="retailerSelect" value="#{graphsBean.retailID}" style="width: 250px"  >  
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{generalBean.retailerList}" var="r" itemValue="#{r.retailerId}"  itemLabel="#{r.retailerName}" />                                       
                                </p:selectOneMenu>    

                        <p:selectOneMenu id="configSelect" value="#{graphsBean.configID}" style="width: 250px"  >  
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{graphsBean.configList}" var="r" itemValue="#{r.ID}"  itemLabel="#{r.configName}" />                                       
                        </p:selectOneMenu>       

                      <p:commandButton id="refreshButton"
                                                 value="Generate" 
                                                 icon="ui-icon-refresh" 
                                                 update="graph" 
                                                 ajax="true"
                                                 global="false"
                                                 actionListener="#{graphsBean.searchMonthTotals()}"/>


                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:toolbarGroup>

                        <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="8" >
                                <h:commandLink>  
                                    <p:graphicImage style="border: none" value="../resources/excel24.png" />  
                                    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="graph" fileName="Month Graph" />  
                                </h:commandLink>  
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:toolbarGroup>

                    </p:toolbar>         

                    <p:spacer width="10" height="10" /> 


                <p:panel header="Month Graph"> 
                <p:lineChart id="graph" value="#{graphsBean.chartModel}" style="width:500px;height:300px" 
                             minY="0" maxY="#{graphsBean.maxTransactions}" 
                             minX="1" maxX="#{graphsBean.maxDays}"
                             showMarkers="false"
                             legendPosition="n"
                             extender="customExtender"/>   
                </p:panel>
```

If anyone can guide me in the correct direction that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: PrimeFaces 3.5 is 'old', PrimeFaces 3.5RC1 is a release candidate of an 'old' version. Did you try a newer version? And your code contains way to much noise. Layout, dialog, database stuff... please read [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question

Comment: Hi, I have made the changes as suggested and removed most of the unnecessary code. The issue is that the data does get populated but the graph does not want to display on the screen. I have tried using a newer library of primefaces but for some reason all the pages give issues then. I did not build the project and when it was done it the latest release of primefaces was 3.5 so I just worked on it.

Comment: So according to your mcve, it works if you use data from a static array instead of a database? And it also works if you remove thetoolbar?

Comment: The data is being inserted into the chart, that works... but the graph does not display, even if I remove the toolbar it still doesn't work

Comment: I know inserting the data works, but if the database is not relevant, create a static arrayList. And if the toolbar and selectOneMenu components are not relevant, remove those to. And try removing the panel and what more that is around the lineChart... it is by a long shot not an mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, there was a Javascript code in the xhtml page that needed to be included to generate the graph.